# GHC 8.0.1 hangs. Explanation or compiler bug?

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-families

Can someone explain why the following code causes GHC 8.0.1 to loop forever on compiling, or is this a bug?

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilyDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

main = return $ f (Just 'c')

data D1 x
data D2

type family TF x = t | t -> x
type instance TF (D1 x, a) = Maybe (TF (x, a))
type instance TF (D2, ()) = Char

f :: TF (x, a) -> ()
f _ = ()
```

Comment: I have no idea, but the documentation for `TypeFamilyDependencies` makes me fear they're not quite ready for prime time. They have unnatural restrictions that don't sit right with me; I wouldn't be shocked if the developers missed a spot.

Comment: If it loops forever that's definitely a bug

Answer (score 3):

The compiler falling into an infinite loop without `UndecidableInstances` or `UndecidableSuperclassCycles` is a compiler bug, as [jberryman stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39085532/ghc-8-0-1-hangs-explanation-or-compiler-bug#comment65521039_39085532). You should report it on the [GHC Trac](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc) site.

I simplified your example a bit, which may or may not clarify things and will likely make your bug report more effective.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilyDependencies #-}

module TFLoop where

import Data.Proxy

main :: IO ()
main = return $ f Proxy Proxy (Just 'c')

data D1 x
data D2

type family TF d a = t | t -> d a
type instance TF (D1 x) a = Maybe (TF x a)
type instance TF D2 () = Char

f :: proxy1 x -> proxy2 a -> TF x a -> ()
f _ _ _ = ()
```